# if-else containing a cy.get as an condition

Tags: cypress

I am trying to create an **if-else** condition that includes `cy.get()`

```
if (!cy.get('.modal.modal--active')) {
    cy.reload()
} else {
    // some codes here
}
```

Upon testing the code the `.modal.modal--active` element is **not** present, instead of executing the `cy.reload()` line, it returns an error.

Expected to find element: `.modal.modal--active`, but never found it.

Is it possible to have the **if** block running and not return AssertionError?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cypress commands should be chained, not used as expressions in `if()` statements.

`cy.get(something)` fails the test when `something` isn't found.

Adding a negative assertion like `cy.get(something).should('not.exist')` does the opposite, it passes when `something` isn't found.

The third way (**undocumented**) is `.should(() => undefined)`, something like this

```js
cy.get('.modal.modal--active')
  .should(() => undefined)          
  .then(activeModal => {
    const found  = activeModal.length  
    if (!found) {
      cy.reload()
    } else {
      ...   
    }
  })
```

The **documented** way is using jQuery `.find()` as follows:

```js
cy.get('body').then((body) => {  // always succeeds
    const modalActive = body.find('.modal.modal--active')
    const found  = activeModal.length
    if (!found) {
      cy.reload()
    } else {
      ...   
    }
})
```

Generally `if/else` is not supported in Cypress testing because best practice is to set the test page so that `if/else` conditions are not necessary.

Comment: To expand on your first point, Cypress commands return a `Chainable<any>` (`Chainable` is a custom type) variable, meaning that a traditional truthy/falsy check in an `if/else` statement would always evaluate as `true` (if Cypress didn't throw an error).

Comment: To be more precise, if you were using Typescript you would see `cy.get()` returns the type `Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>` (custom type is not really a thing). In Javascript the browser sees an `Object` which can never be false.